Locally stored images not working after upgrade to expo 51
After upgrading from Expo SDK 49 to 51 my images are broken. The images are stored locally in the assets folder of the project and I use expo-image.
"dependencies": {
"@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.23.1",
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.7",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
"@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.12",
"expo": "^51.0.8",
"expo-application": "~5.9.1",
"expo-av": "~14.0.5",
"expo-constants": "~16.0.1",
"expo-device": "~6.0.2",
"expo-font": "~12.0.5",
"expo-image-picker": "~15.0.5",
"expo-intent-launcher": "~11.0.1",
"expo-linear-gradient": "~13.0.2",
"expo-localization": "~15.0.3",
"expo-notifications": "~0.28.3",
"expo-secure-store": "~13.0.1",
"expo-splash-screen": "~0.27.4",
"expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1",
"expo-updates": "~0.25.14",
...
"expo-image": "~1.12.9"

},
An example on how I fetch the images.
/assets
/screens
   homescreen.tsx <- snip below is from here
package.json

<Image
    contentFit="contain"
    style={styles.headerImage}
    source={require("../assets/images/ArtHomePage1.png")}
  />

I went over the documentation and the changelogs between 49 to 50 and 50 to 51 and I couldn't find anything back regarding a change to the images or local files.

What do you mean by broken? It's not displaying an image, it's throwing an error, etc?

@MichaelBrenndoerfer bad wording on my part. But on expo 49 the images (which were stored in an assets/images folder) were showing in the app, but after upgrading to expo 51 they don't show/are visible. It's like they are not loaded.

This was a dependency issue caused by the upgrade. I saw the response on https://stackoverflow.com/a/78523103/1174076 and this is it. I had run the doctor before, but somehow it must have not worked, so I ran it again:
npx expo-doctor@latest

And 3 dependencies were listed as requiring an update, most notably expo itself:
Detailed check results:

The following packages should be updated for best compatibility with the installed expo version:
  expo@51.0.9 - expected version: ~51.0.11
  expo-splash-screen@0.27.4 - expected version: ~0.27.5
  react-native@0.74.1 - expected version: 0.74.2
Your project may not work correctly until you install the expected versions of the packages.
Found outdated dependencies
Advice: Use 'npx expo install --check' to review and upgrade your dependencies.

So running npx expo install --check fixed it.

@rafbanaan try this and let me know if it works.

Now I'm getting error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'transformFile')
when doing the doctor check I get this, but when I do npm i metro-resolver@~0.80.8 it doesnt update the package
Expected package metro-resolver@~0.80.8 Found invalid:   metro-resolver@0.76.9

Ok, fixed the above with clean install of all packages and removing the package.lock file!
The fix above answer works! :)

@bitoiu you saved my life...

Happy to help @IsaRota
